# Removing a Voltage Regulator after exchanging a dynamo for an alternator

Tags: electrical, voltage-regulator

> Authi Mini 998 MK2 from 1972 (spanish mini)

I **removed my dynamo** and **replaced it with an alternator**. Alternators have internal voltage regulators making the existing voltage regulator innecesary, redundant and one more piece that can eventually go wrong.

I was re-wiring my entire car after a dog related accident *(my pet pulled out the wire harness trying to catch a rat)* ... so what better time to remove the regulator and probably tidy out the wiring diagram.
My guess is I should **just bridge all terminals to eachother**, this is 51-67-30 all together.

Am I correct in my assumption?

[image: Dy]

Comment: "I poked 'n stroked till my wrist got numb
But I still didn't hear no Dinah-Moe Humm"  Frank Zappa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You need to connect the wire on terminal 30 to the wire on terminal 51, that is assuming you have not replaced the wire to the generator. If you have then you need to connect the alternator to the battery positive with a with suitable for the current output of the alternator.

Then you need to find the ignition warning light wire and perhaps use the wire from terminal 67 that went to the field terminal on the old generator connect that to the small terminal on the alternator - assuming you have an alternator from the period then a Lucas 16ACR will be excellent for this.

Comment: That's a solid response, thank you so much.
Just to make sure, if I didn't connect the wire form 67 to the small terminal on the alt I'd just be missing the battery indicator, I have a amp and volt meter on my dashboard so it's not essential.

Comment: It may be essential as it might be the voltage signal for the regulator... can’t remember but better to connect it.

Comment: Much apreciated Mike!